# Get latest posts from multiple categories

Tags: get-posts

So I am using the code below to retrieve the latest 5 posts from 5 different categories.

The problem is that it outputs the latest 5 posts from only the first category in the array, even if there are newer posts in the other 4 categories.

If I remove the first category from the array, then it simply outputs the latest 5 posts from the next category in the array.  It never gets to the remaining categories.

What I wanted to do was to output the newest 5 posts from *all* the 5 categories *combined*.  What can I do to fix that?

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'category' => 15,16,17,18,19);
$myposts = get_posts( $args ); ?>
<?php foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 choices here, you either need to set the category as an array e.g.

```
$args = array( 
 'posts_per_page' => 5,
 'category' => array(15,16,17,18,19)
);
```

You can't just add the numbers in a list but I can't find any documentation that the category element allows multiples (as the name is category)

The other option is to use wp_query and category__in

```
$query = new WP_Query(
 array(
  'category__in' => array(15,16,17,18,19),
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'post_type' => 'post',
 )
 );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
 while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  $query->the_post();
  // do something
 }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

These will get the 5 last posts from any of those categories, if you want to get a post from each of them then the query needs to be a lot different

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem in the array construction.
You have that :

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'category' => 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
);
```

And you probably need that :

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'category' => [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
);
```